# SQL Query for continuous eligibility dates

Tags: sql-server

How can i write query for the below.

I have data like

```
id   eff date   term date
 C   20000101   20050228
 C   20000501   20120229
 C   20060101   20120301
```

I need to check for continuous eligibility and if continuous i need to get rid of other records. For above example i need the output as

```
id   Eff date   Term date
C    20000101  20120301
```

I need to remove the overlapping ranges.In the above example i have overlapping ranges of eligibility. If i had another input record(4th one) say C 20130101 20130531 Then my output should be two records. C 20000010 20120301 and C 20130101 20130531

Comment: what do you mean with "continuous eligibility"? why only that row should be selected? please expand your request.

Comment: I need to remove the overlapping ranges.In the above example i have overlapping ranges of eligibility. If i had another input record(4th one) say C 20130101 20130531 Then my output should be two records. C 20000010 20120301 and C 20130101 20130531

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the business rules for continuous eligibility - but wonder if just this will do it:

```
 SELECT id, min(Eff_date), max(Term_date)
 FROM my_table
 GROUP BY id
```

Comment: I need to remove the overlapping ranges.In the above example i have overlapping ranges of eligibility. If i had another input record(4th one) say C 20130101 20130531 Then my output should be two records. C 20000101 20120301 and C 20130101 20130531

Comment: This is possible to do in SQL but I think needs analytic functions such as LAG so that we can access a prior row.  Will your DBMS support analytic functions.   Alternatively, my preference would be do to this procedurally.  What language or environment are you running this query from?